# The boundary of open and closed sets in R

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers

Consider the open and closed intervals in $\mathbb{R}$, respectively, $(a,b)$ and $[a,b]$. Clearly $(a,b)$ is an open set and $[a,b]$ is a closed set, and the set of boundary points of $(a,b)$ and $[a,b]$ is $\{a,b\}$. I know that the interior of the boundary of $[a,b]$ is just $\{a,b\}$ but why is the interior of the boundary of $(a,b)$ empty although the boundary of $(a,b)$ and $[a,b]$ are the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The boundary of the interior of $[a, b]$ is the boundary of $(a, b)$ (which, coincidentally, is also the interior of $(a,b)$), and is $\{a, b\}$. The interior of $\{a, b\}$ is still $\emptyset$.

Comment: This answer would (in my opinion) be improved if it were spelled out *why* the interior of $\{a,b\}$ is empty.

Answer (score 3):

The boundary of a subset $A$ of a topological space $X$ is the set of all points $x \in X$ such that every open neighbourhood of $x$ contains points in $A$ and points in $X \setminus A$. Using this definition, it is easy to see that the boundary of a non-empty interval (like $(a, b)$ or $(a, b]$ or ...) with lower bound $a$ and upper bound $b$ is the two element set $\{a, b\}$. The interior of any finite subset of $\Bbb{R}$ is empty: the interior of a set $A$ is the largest open set contained in $A$, but a finite subset of $\Bbb{R}$ contains no open subsets, so its interior is empty. (Your claim that the interior of the boundary of $[a, b]$ is $\{a, b\}$ is wrong.)